# Quickly loading UITableViewCell images from disk

Tags: uitableview, uikit

I'm building a country picker `UITableViewController`, where each `UITableViewCell` contains a `UIImage` of the country's flag. I've tried loading each cell's `UIImage` object from `.xcassets` in my `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` on the main thread, like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let imageName = UIImage(named: "US.png")
        imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        return cell
}
```

which yields an FPS of roughly ~46. Then I try the same operation asynchronously:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let imageName = UIImage(named: "US.png")
                imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }

            return cell
    }
```

which improves my scrolling FPS to ~55, which isn't awful. But I think it can be further optimized.

What would be the best way of quickly loading images from disk in a high-performing scrollable `UITableView`? Third party library?

Answer (score 1):

You are still loading on the main thread, probably something like

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    DispatchQueue("Somequeue").async {
        let imageName = UIImage(named: "US.png")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Will be a little bit faster. The image is loaded away from the main thread and once it's loaded you go back to the main thread to set the image. However, this approach might result in some weird behaviour if you scroll rapidly. The cell will be reused and you might end up setting the wrong image on the cell if an old image loads after the newest image does.

It's probably best to implement some sort of queue mechanism that uses its own DispatchQueue and knows how to cancel or ignore old requests.

The main point is to take the image loading away from the main thread :)